# How to use SQL Server's GETDATE() when system time is off?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, systemtime

I'm writing an application which needs the accurate time (accurate to a few seconds, nothing crazy). The application is in C# and it interfaces with SQL Server, both reside on the same machine. In my application code I'm getting the time from an NTP server but I want to be able to write SQL statements which use GETDATE() instead of having to write the current time in the SQL statement.

Unfortunately, the system time on the server doesn't stay accurate over time. Is there a way to use GETDATE() when the system time is off? I'd rather avoid writing code which retrieves the time from an NTP server and then updates the system time.

Comment: You can run a real ntp client on the sql server to keep it's clock (and therefore getdate()) synchronized.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need to write any code yourself to talk to NTP - you should just be able to enable the Windows Time Service which will do it itself. If you find your system clock is still drifting too quickly, that suggests there may be something wrong with the computer - the time service should sync often enough that it stays pretty close.

EDIT: If as suggested the Windows Time Service doesn't maintain enough accuracy, I'm sure there are plenty of other NTP clients which will run as a service in Windows. I'm pretty sure I used to run [NetTime](http://www.timesynctool.com/)... I definitely wouldn't suggest writing it yourself though, simply on the grounds that it's already been done.

Comment: The problem is that the windows time service was designed to keep clocks close enough for kerberos authentication to work (kerberos tickets need a 5 minute window).  It will keep clocks within a few seconds, but isn't close to a proper NTP solution.

Comment: @StrayCatDBA: That surprises me - but as you said in your comment, you could run another NTP service easily enough. Will edit that into my answer.

Comment: [overview of windows time service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773061(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_WTS) Also,  [kb939322](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939322/en-us) describes the limits of accuracy.  And yes, I have been bitten by this before.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try NetTime as an NTP client.